# About Pipeline Architecture's Data Dependency

Tags: pipeline, cpu-architecture

I'm confused of following instructions.
$zero is register always containing value of 0

I1 : addi $t1, $t10, -10

I2 : lw $t2, 0($t1)

I3 : lw $t3, 0($t2)

I4 : sw $t3, 0($t4)

I5 : sub $t3, $zero, $t3

I6 : addi $t3, $t3, 1

How can I find data dependency here?

There are some straightforward like $t1 in I1-I2

but what about $t3, between I3, I4, I5, I6? I'm confused about it.

Can anyone help me to find all dependencies here?

Answer (score 0):

There are three kind of data dependencies, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dependency).
I1 and I2, I2 and I3 -- read after write -- flow data dependency
I3 and I4, I4 and I5, I5 and I6 -- write after write -- output data dependency